# Function in Discriminated Union Constraining the Type of a Generic Parameter

Tags: .net, f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to port some Haskell code to F# and I am getting a strange error I don't know how to get around. I have a discriminated union with a function defined as below:

```
type OtherType =
    OtherType1 of string
    | OtherType2 of string
type MyType<'a> = 
    MySub1 of DateTime * string * (float -> MyType<'a>)
    | MySub2 of 'a
    | MySub3 of DateTime * string * (bool -> MyType<'a>)
```

Later I have a function that works on this type as such

```
let fun1 date myType (myFun2: ('b -> MyType<'a>)) = 
    match myType with
    | OtherType1(string1) -> MySub1(date, string1, myFun2)
    | OtherType2(string1) -> MySub3(date, string1, myFun2)
```

This then constrains myFun2 to type (float -> MyType<'a>). Is there any way to prevent this from happening and keep k generic?

The result is the second pattern match falls.

Thank you.

Update:

Looking at the Haskell code that I am trying to replicate I think the issue is that in the Haskell version OtherType is a GADT and OtherType1 becomes OtherType Double and OtherType2 becomes OtherType Bool. Then myFun2 would be able to perform both of those functions. Here is the code if anyone is interested.

```
data OtherType a where
    OtherType1 :: String -> OtherType Double
    OtherType2 :: String -> OtherType Bool 

data MyType a = MySub1 UTCTime String (Double -> MyType a)
    | MySub2 a
    | MySub3 UTCTime String (Bool -> MyType a)

myFun1 :: UTCTime -> OtherType a -> MyType a
myFun1 time o = myFun1' o MySub2
    where
        myFun1' :: OtherType b-> (b -> MyType a) -> MyType a
        myFun1' (OtherType1 name) k = MySub1 time name k
        myFun1' (OtherType2 name) k = MySub3 time name k
```

So I guess the question to ask is, can GADTs be replicated in F#?

Comment: `k` does not appear in any of your code.  Also you are missing a `|` before the `MySub1` in the forst block of code.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. The | is missing and K was supposed to be myFun2. I have corrected this.

Comment: Some more details: I assume `match myType with |Mysub` should be `MySub2`.  Furthermore I don't understand why you think `myFun2` should be generic - it must have type `float ->MyType<'a>` by the definition of `MyType`.

Comment: I should have put this in the original post but the reason I want myFun2 to be generic is because I want to add MySub3 to MyType with parameters of DateTime * string * (bool -> MyType2<'a>) and have myFun2 satisfy the function in that statement too.

Comment: Just to add the type to be matched is not part of the type defined above. That was my fault. Again, I should have taken more time to write this out.

Comment: I can think of 2 ways to do this - `myfun2` takes a Discriminated Union as the argument or you abandon type safety and use box/unbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30199/discussion-between-ochowie-and-john-palmer)

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you posted your Haskell code as well, since it's not entirely clear how you expect the type parameters in `fun1` to be quantified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no faithful way to represent arbitrary GADTs in F#.  However, given the structure of your GADT and the function you're writing, it should be possible use the following (clunky) encoding:

```
// Module for witnessing the equality of two types
module Eq =
    // opaque type equating 'a and 'b
    type eq<'a,'b> = private Eq of ('a -> 'b) * ('b -> 'a) with
        member eq.Apply(v) = match eq with | Eq(f,_) -> f v
        member eq.Unapply(v) = match eq with | Eq(_,g) -> g v

    // constructs an eq<'a,'a>
    [<GeneralizableValue>]
    let refl<'a> : eq<'a,'a> = Eq(id,id)

    // Not used, but included for completeness
    let sym (Eq(f,g)) = Eq(g,f)
    let trans (Eq(f,g)) (Eq(h,i)) = Eq(f >> h, i >> g)

    // ideally, we'd also provide a way to lift an eq<'a,'b> to an eq<F<'a>,F<'b>>, but this can't be expressed by F#'s type system

type OtherType<'a> =
| OtherType1 of Eq.eq<'a,double> * string
| OtherType2 of Eq.eq<'a,bool> * string

// "smart" constructors
let otherType1 s = OtherType1(Eq.refl, s)
let otherType2 s = OtherType2(Eq.refl, s)

type MyType<'a> =
| MySub1 of DateTime * string * (float -> MyType<'a>)
| MySub2 of 'a
| MySub3 of DateTime * string * (bool -> MyType<'a>)

let fun1 date myType myFun2 = 
    match myType with
    | OtherType1(eq, string1) -> MySub1(date, string1, eq.Unapply >> myFun2)
    | OtherType2(eq, string1) -> MySub3(date, string1, eq.Unapply >> myFun2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks close to what I need. One question, how would I ever pull the actual value out and apply myFun2 to it?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want Rank-2 types that can be emulated with generic methods

```
open System

type OtherType =
    OtherType1 of string
    | OtherType2 of string

type MyType<'a> = 
    MySub1 of DateTime * string * (float -> MyType<'a>)
    | MySub2 of 'a
    | MySub3 of DateTime * string * (bool -> MyType<'a>)

type F<'a> = abstract member Invoke<'b> : 'b -> MyType<'a>

let fun1 date myType (myFun2: F<'a>) = 
    match myType with
    | OtherType1(string1) -> MySub1(date, string1, myFun2.Invoke)
    | OtherType2(string1) -> MySub3(date, string1, myFun2.Invoke)

fun1 DateTime.Now (OtherType1 "a") {
    new F<_> with
        member this.Invoke v = failwith "to be implemented"
    }
```

Comment: So I tried this but when I implement the Invoke member I get an error that the code is not generic. The type variable 'a could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.